# How to increase Synfusion graph values sizes?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have Syncfusion line Spline graph in Xamarin Forms:

```
<chart:SfChart>
<chart:SplineSeries
           ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomDates}"
           XBindingPath="Date"
           YBindingPath="Severity">
</chart:SplineSeries>
</chart:SfChart>
```

How do I increase label sizes?

[image]

Comment: first [hit](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5545/how-to-customize-the-axis-labels) when googling "sfchart label size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason hinted, to increase the size of the label, you can **customize** the `FontSize="25"` of the property `ChartAxisLabelStyle` like below:

```
<chart:SfChart> 

       <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

             <chart:CategoryAxis>

                  <chart:CategoryAxis.LabelStyle>
                       <chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle FontSize="25"/>

                  </chart:CategoryAxis.LabelStyle>

             </chart:CategoryAxis>

        </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
       
</chart:SfChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize axis labels using the LabelStyle property, and you can increase the size of the axis labels using the FontSize property. Below, I have attached an example for reference:

```
<chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <chart:DateTimeAxis>

                <chart:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle>

                    <chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle TextColor="Red" FontSize="10" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                </chart:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle>

            </chart:DateTimeAxis>
</chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
```

[image]

Reference links:

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/axis#label-customization
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5545/how-to-customize-the-axis-labels

Note: Working in syncfusion